# jquery way to get $(this).id=something.val()

Tags: jquery

```
<tr>
 <td><input type="checkbox">
 </td>
 <td class='something'>13</td>
 <td class='something2'>55</td>
 <td class='something3'>552</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><input type="checkbox">
 </td>
 <td class='something'>23</td>
 <td class='something2'>35</td>
 <td class='something3'>155</td>
</tr>
 <td><input type="checkbox">
 </td>
 <td class='something'>323</td>
 <td class='something2'>135</td>
 <td class='something3'>255</td>
</tr>
```

when check box is checked for first two tr and submit button is pressed, I want to get the html value for class = 'something2' from jquery file and use to push them to php file so that I can process them.
How do I get the value?

I want to say something like $(this).class=something2.val();  How do I say this in jquery?

(trying to make it clear?, IF first two TR has checkbox checked, how can I say I want val() of class something2(which will get me 55 and 35)

Comment: not yet clear what you want ?

Comment: Exactly, What you want to achieve

Comment: Replace val() with [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

Comment: first two tr has checkbox checked. Which means they are selected. Once submit button is pressed, I want to get value of class='something2'.. which means 55 and 35. How do I get these value in jquery

Comment: how is this not clear??

Comment: Sorry, but it's not clear - it seems too specific and will affect any answer provided.   For example if you tick one tickbox, should it give you "something1" value?  If you tick all 3, should it give "something3".  If you pick the 1st and 3rd, should it still give you something2 for 1st and 3rd (which doesn't match your requirement of "if first 2 ticked")..  **It *sounds like* you want to get the value of something2 for each row that is ticked** - which is much easier than checking specifically if the first two are ticked only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should find your checked checkboxes and use `.map` to get the `.text()` of the cells you're after.

```js
$('button').on('click',function(){
  
  var result = $(':checkbox:checked').map(function(){
      return $(this).parents('tr').find('td.something2').text();
  }).get();
  console.log(result);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
 <td><input type="checkbox">
 </td>
 <td class='something'>13</td>
 <td class='something2'>55</td>
 <td class='something3'>552</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><input type="checkbox">
 </td>
 <td class='something'>23</td>
 <td class='something2'>35</td>
 <td class='something3'>155</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><input type="checkbox">
 </td>
 <td class='something'>323</td>
 <td class='something2'>135</td>
 <td class='something3'>255</td>
</tr>
</table>
<button>click me</button>
```

Comment: I think the user wants to pick the class(something#) depending on number of checkboxes selected, not sure though

Comment: @SamGhatak nor am I. Lets wait and see what they say.

Comment: yes, so this solution works but if I wanted something and something2 ? (Actually, I got this.. thank you so much!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.text() or .html()` functions.

```
$('.something2').text() or $('.something2').html()
```

Comment: that is not gonna work as it will select all which has class something2.. I said, first two TR was selected so with your solution, it will select all 3 TR.

Comment: You can add a class to the tr and then find .something2 in that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(this).parent('td').siblings('.something2').text();
```

Comment: Does the user want something2 to be chosen dynamically?

Comment: Yes, dynamically based on whether row has checkbox checked.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two parts of the answer:
First to pick values of those `td`s,you should use `text()` or `html()` instead of `val()`.
Second to construct the logic of choosing the `td`s, I would prefer doing it in click of submit button. First pick the selected checkboxes and number of selected checkboxes. Then for each selected checkbox take the text out of a `td` at sibling level with class `'something'+(number of selected checkbox)`.

```
var selected = $('input:checkbox:checked');
var selectedVals = [];
var numSelected = selected.length;
selected.each(function() {
    value = $(this).parents('tr').find('td.something'+numSelected.toString()).text();
    selectedVals.push(value);
});
```

Hope it helps.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q5z9tc3r/1/

Comment: I guess @Jamiec has a elegant way of doing it :)